# Replace statement creating duplicate lines

Tags: powershell

I'm using the code below

```
$content | ForEach-Object { 

$addresseeName = $_.Substring(11,50)            
$example = 'X' * 50                             
if ($_.Substring(0,10) -eq 'ADDRESSEE0')        
{ 
    $_ -replace $addresseeName, $example        

} 
else 
{ 
  $_ 
} 


$addresseeName2 = $_.Substring(62,50)           
$example = 'Y' * 50                             
if ($_.Substring(0,10) -eq 'ADDRESSEE0')        
{ 
    $_ -replace $addresseeName2, $example       
} 
else 
{ 
  $_ 
}
```

Text file before:

```
ABSINVEST2|Y|N|                                                                                                                                 
ADDRESSEE0|Name Name Letters Letters & Financial             |                                                  |19 Greemount House            |
ADDRSDETAS|                                                  |                                                  |
```

Text File After:

```
ABSINVEST2|Y|N|                                                                                                                                 
ADDRESSEE0|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|                                                  |19 Greemount House            
ADDRESSEE0|Samp less Independent Examples & Exampless s      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|19 Greemount House            
ADDRSDETAS|                                                  |                                                  |
```

I am attempting to mask particular fields (positions). Can anyone help me as to why the line is being duplicated for every IF Else statement?

Updating code I got working:

```
$content | 
  ForEach-Object { 

  $addresseeName = $_.Substring(11,50)
  $addresseeName2 = $_.Substring(62,50)
  $example = 'X' * 50
    if ($_.Substring(0,10) -eq 'ADDRESSEE0')    


    { 
        $_.replace($addresseeName, $example).replace($addresseeName2, $example)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, because you are duplicating it (your current script outputs it twice). Try this instead:

```
$content | ForEach-Object { 
    $addresseeName = $_.Substring(11,50)            
    $example = 'X' * 50                             

    if ($_.Substring(0,10) -eq 'ADDRESSEE0')        
    { 
        $_ = $_ -replace $addresseeName, $example        

    } 

    $addresseeName2 = $_.Substring(62,50)           
    $example = 'Y' * 50                             

    if ($_.Substring(0,10) -eq 'ADDRESSEE0')        
    { 
        $_ = $_ -replace $addresseeName2, $example       
    } 

    $_ 
}
```

This modifies the current line variable `$_` by setting it when performing the replace and then only outputting it once at the end (whether it has changed or not).

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I did get what I want by using the following.

  $addresseeName = $_.Substring(11,50)
  $addresseeName2 = $_.Substring(62,50)
  $example = 'X' * 50
    if ($_.Substring(0,10) -eq 'ADDRESSEE0')             
 { 
     $_.replace($addresseeName, $example).replace($addresseeName2, $example)   #replace Addresse Name fields with Example (50 X's)
  
    }

I will have to do this for a number of variables so was trying to tidy it up a little to work with

Comment: I see, so doing two replace methods on the single variable. I'm not sure why what I have suggested above hasn't worked though, it should do, it's just using a variable to store the changes vs doing them all at once. I tested it with the text you provided and got the result you expected. But hey, glad you got it working regardless.

Comment: I fully expect it is something I've done wrong ha. Thanks , I will update the original post with the code I got working. Thanks